# SetTimeOut function inside ngOnInit of Angular component while using Angular Material DataTable

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, settimeout

I was going through an Angular code in one of my existing projects and found below snippet. 
We are using `Angular material datatable` to render the view on the page

```
export class Component implements OnInit,AfterViewInit{

  private dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Product> = null;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator; 

  columnsToDisplay = ['productId','productname'];
  constructor(private _service : DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this._service.getProducts().subscribe(
     ((data : Product[]) => this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data)),
     () => console.log('THIS IS ERROR')
    );
    setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator);
    //this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator; 
  }

}
```

My question is :

1) Since `this.service.getData()` returns an `Observable` and `subscribe` will be called asynchronously whenever the `HttpResponse` is available , 
     does operation inside `setTimeout` function will be called **ONLY AFTER** the `subscribe` method is called ?

2) I have seen that `ngAfterViewInit` method also contains exactly the same code as in `setTimeout` method in `ngOnInit` method

3) But when this method is called `(ngAfterViewInit)` , `this.products` is still NULL indicating that subscribe is not yet called '

4) Is that the reason `setTimeout` is called inside `ngOnInit` method ?

5)If this is the case , what is the use of `ngAfterViewInit` method ?

Comment: From what I can tell there's no reason to have either of the `setTimeout`s. It seems like it might have been done to set a default value for products, but that doesn't need to be done asynchronously.

Comment: I have added few more details in my question. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to simplify the description:

1. setTimeout puts the inside function in the end of the javascript queue so while javascript process is running it will pop up from the stack and call the operation. anything in the queue will get called only if the stack is empty. so `setTimeout` tells javascript to hold the this code till you finish your work.
2. subscribe and observable: observable is async data structure so once you subscribe to it you can never now how much time it will take to call the subscribe method. in other words, subscribe will get called only if as example http response returns.

Back to your question: you can not know when your setTimeout code get called but theoretically it will get called before subscribe (javascript engine faster than http response).

If you need to initialize some data table structure only after you get the data from the http request you should put it inside the `subscribe` method and no need for setTimeout.

`ngAfterViewInit` is used by angular to tell the developer that in this stage your `view` is ready and you can as an example use elementRef.

`ngOnInit` is used by angular to tell the developer that all the inputs and directives ...etc.

Comment: But then why is my this.dataSource is NULL when ngAfterViewInit is called ? How should I make sure that this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;  assignment happens after this.dataSource gets the value . Current cod seems not working

Comment: `    this._service.getProducts().subscribe(
     ((data : Product[]) => {this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data)}; this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;),
     () => console.log('THIS IS ERROR')
    );`

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

1) It depends. the subscription execute the code only when the action is done. So, when the `this.service.getData()` has finished its job. The setTimeout do the job after a delay. If the subscription need less time than the setTimeout, it will be executed first.

2) Maybe you were trying to notice when the function is executed?

3) the AfterViewInit is fired multiple times. You can check like this `if(!!something)` and then execute some code.

4) you should **ALWAYS** avoid to use settimeout (just use it for debug purposes).

**EDIT:**

ngOnInit() {

```
this._service.getProducts().subscribe(
 ((data : Product[]) => this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data)),
 () => console.log('THIS IS ERROR')
);
setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator);
//this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
```

}
`

Let's simply this code a bit:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.doStuff()
  .subscribe(result => {
    this.functionA();
  },
  err => {
    //Do other stuff in case of an error
  });

  this.functionB();
}

functionA(){
  console.log("Hello,");
}

functionB(){
  console.log("world!");
}
```

The output of this code will be:

`world!Hello,`

**But why?**

That's because of the `observable` pattern.

You can imagine that as you walking with two people: one that know english, one that doesn't. So even if you say "How are you?" first to the guy who doesn't know english, he will need time to understand what did you say and answer you. At the same time, the other guy (that know english very well) answer you instantly.

The example of `functionA` and `functionB` is the same. FunctionA is executed **only** when the subscription has catch something. That's why it isn't fired first. You can see that putting a debug point here:

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.service.doStuff()
      .subscribe(result => {
      --->  this.functionA();
      },
      err => {
        //Do other stuff in case of an error
      });

      --->  this.functionB();
    }
```

hope to have explained well this.

**Now let's move on**, let's use the timeout:

```
 ngOnInit() {
          this.service.doStuff()
          .subscribe(result => {
            this.functionA();
          },
          err => {
            //Do other stuff in case of an error
          });

          settimeout(() => {
            this.functionB();
          }, 500);
        }
```

**Which function will be executed first?**

*Spoiler: You can't know that.*

If you are wondering why, it's easy: You know exactly that the functionB will be called after 500ms, but you can't know how much time will use the subscription to be ready. So if you are lucky, and your subscription usually need about 500ms to complete, you can try to reload the page several time, sometimes you will see `Hello, world!`, sometimes you will see `world!Hello,`.

To answer in a better way at your questions: I don't really know why did you put the code like this, literally no idea.

The ngAfterViewInit is a `life-cycle` called **after** the ngOnInit, and execute the logic after Angular has fully initialized a component's view.

Comment: I have modified the question to give more details

Answer (score 0):

**1.** no , setTimeout will be called only once and before subscribe as its outside of its context.

**2.** because of Asynchronous update ,  if we update properties asynchronously the values will not be updated when the verification loop is running and we get no error.

**3.** the ViewChild is available only after ngAfterViewInit. it populates the children when creating a view and so they are available earlier.

**4.** ngOnInit lifecycle hook is triggered before the DOM update operation and will give no error. ngOnInit lifecycle hook is triggered after the bindings have been processed . ngAfterViewInit is invoked when the view is initially rendered i.e. it's called after a component's view, and its children's views, are created.

**5.** ngAfterViewInit() should be called after a component's view, and its children's views, are created, most importantly children's ngAfterViewInit()s are called before the parent's ngAfterViewInit().